# Schematron validation

Tags: xml, schematron

I need to create a rule for an element to check if it has the following format:

**"Document created [DateTime]. Accepted [DateTime]."** , where **[DateTime]** should be DD.MM.YYYY.

Have already read lots of documentation, but still can't handle this.

Comment: What have you already tried ?

Comment: I can make this creating several rules using substring. But it ain't look like best practice. I've been waiting for some instrument which would let me do an element validation template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex , to validate date format, after you extract the date format from the string

```
 ^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```